# Automatically create MediaWiki page from template input

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wikipedia, transclusion

I have a template that gets multiple user inputs. For one of these specific inputs, I wanted to automatically create a new page with the content of that input.

Example: wiki.com/wiki/Article

```
{{Template
Data = Data1
}}
```

I want to have a page automatically created from what was inputted into Data. So, a new subpage of the current page (called Data) would be created.

wiki.com/wiki/Article/Data has the following

```
Data1
```

Is this possible in MediaWiki software, either by an extension or the software itself?

EDIT: This extension http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiDB will do basically what I described above. It will define data to a page that doesn't exist and allow you to retrieve this data for usage elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions that might help you:

- http://semantic-mediawiki.org
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiDB

More important: Using Semantic MediaWiki (and possibly also WikiDB, I haven't tried that), you can also find far more convenient ways to store data, than by creating pages like you are suggesting. I can't think of any scenario where creating pages just for storing data from a template would be the best option.